# How to recover data from a corrupted pen drive

Tags: hard-drive, pen

My pen drive is unreadable, when I plug it in the computer it does not appear on the computer even dist 1 is also not shown. How can the data can be recovered.

Comment: what have you done soma to recover the data....??

Answer (score 0):

If the drive does not show up in the computer at all, even the Windows Logical Disk Manager, then you need to take the drive to a professional data recovery service. Don't be surprised if you're quoted a price over $1000, and figure out exactly how much that data is worth to you.